# Grouping series of observations in a SensorThings API

Tags: sensorthings

I'm working on an API based on the SensorThings standard.

One of the requirements is to return groups of observations to the client, based on time intervals provided by another service. That service provides phases with start and end times and I need to group together measurements that fall between the boundaries of these intervals.

Conceptually, let's I have a request with several time intervals:

http://example.sensorup.com/v1.0/Datastreams(503292)/Observations?$filter=phenomenonTime%20ge%202017-01-03T12:00:00Z%20and%20phenomenonTime%20lt%202017-01-03T15:00:00Z%20or%20phenomenonTime%20ge%202017-01-03T17:00:00Z%20and%20phenomenonTime%20lt%202017-01-03T18:00:00Z&$resultFormat=dataArray

Result would look something like this (which obviously isn't valid):

```
{
  "dataArray@iot.count": 32,
  "Datastream@iot.navigationLink": "http://example.sensorup.com/v1.0/Datastreams(503292)",
  "components": [
    "@iot.id",
    "phenomenonTime",
    "result",
    "resultTime"
  ],
  "dataArray": [
        [
            [
                3591202,
                "2017-01-03T12:00:07.646Z",
                "4",
                null
            ],
            [
                3590989,
                "2017-01-03T12:00:22.655Z",
                "2",
                null
            ],
            [
                3590842,
                "2017-01-03T12:00:39.597Z",
                "6",
                null
            ],[],[],[]....
        ], [
            [
                3591202,
                "2017-01-03T17:00:07.646Z",
                "4",
                null
            ],
            [
                3590989,
                "2017-01-03T17:00:22.655Z",
                "2",
                null
            ],
            [
                3590842,
                "2017-01-03T17:00:39.597Z",
                "6",
                null
            ],[],[],[]....
        ]
  ]
}
```

An obvious and easy solution would be to return a array of arrays as the `value` of `Observations`, but that would break conformity with the standard.

Another simple approach would be to get the client to issue separate requests for each group of observations, but that would require extra round-trips between the client and the server, which might be inefficient.

I suppose that could be optimized by using batch requests, but the format seems a bit complicated to implement, and I'd rather not force the front-end JavaScript developer to deal with it.

Is there any other solution that I could implement?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the OGC SensorThings Multi-Datastream extension fits what you want to do. http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/15-078r6/15-078r6.html#77

Example #34 in the standard:

```
{
  "@iot.id": 1,
  "@iot.selfLink": "http://example.org/v1.0/Observations(1)",
  "FeatureOfInterest@iot.navigationLink": "Observations(1)/FeatureOfInterest",
  "MultiDatastream@iot.navigationLink": "Observations(1)/MultiDatastream",
  "phenomenonTime": "2014-12-31T11:59:59.00+08:00",
  "resultTime": "2014-12-31T11:59:59.00+08:00",
  "result": [ 
    25, 
    65,
    "clear" 
  ]
}
```

Comment: I looked into the MultiDatastream extension but it seems to solve a different problem. With MultiDatastream, you have several measurements that happen at the same time and you want to group them together. For instance you may use it to serve temperature and air pressure sampled at the same regular intervals. My use case is different: I have a single measurement type and I need to group values inside time buckets. For instance I have a temperature and I want to return the temperature between 1am and 2am, between 6am and 8am and between 10am and 11am, each interval being a disctinct group.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to return data for a certain time interval, you can use the $filter query option.  Then if you would like to group them together, you can use the $resultFormat=dataArray.

For example, the following query gives you the results in data array between 2017-01-01T12:00:00Z and 2017-01-01T15:00:00Z and the result is in data array.

Request:
http://example.sensorup.com/v1.0/Datastreams(503292)/Observations?$filter=phenomenonTime%20ge%202017-01-03T12:00:00Z%20and%20phenomenonTime%20lt%202017-01-03T15:00:00Z&$resultFormat=dataArray

Result:

```
{
  "dataArray@iot.count": 32,
  "Datastream@iot.navigationLink": "http://example.sensorup.com/v1.0/Datastreams(503292)",
  "components": [
    "@iot.id",
    "phenomenonTime",
    "result",
    "resultTime"
  ],
  "dataArray": [
    [
      3591202,
      "2017-01-03T14:56:07.646Z",
      "4",
      null
    ],
    [
      3590989,
      "2017-01-03T14:46:22.655Z",
      "2",
      null
    ],
    [
      3590842,
      "2017-01-03T14:39:39.597Z",
      "6",
      null
    ],[],[],[]....

  ]
}
```

Comment: I need to return data for several time intervals, grouping data within each interval together. I'll edit my question based on your example.